# x86 how do I know that a register value is not needed

Tags: assembly, x86

Many operations on x86 implicitly write values to registers - e.g. addition would also update eflags register. My question is: is it possible to tell when the data stored in registers will not be needed anymore? For example, it is valid to assume that I perform some operation that updates register R1, then perform 1000s more operations and then fetch value from R1, expecting it to be what was stored there before? Would compiler generate such a code?
Thanks!

Comment: In what sort of situation? In the most general case, the only real guaranteed thing is that if it gets overwritten before the next use, the current value is not needed. In the context of structured programming you may be able to say more.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to understand (reverse engineer) some disassembled code?

Comment: @harold - what I had in mind is the following: it is possible that the code generated by the compiler will look like this that we will store a value to some register (explicitly or implicitly), then we would perform many more operations not touching this register and then some operation will use it? It there any rule that says we should use register values straight away?

Comment: There's no such rule.

Comment: Registers that appear to be "abandoned" may still get read arbitrarily far into the future. The only way to tell is to actually look there.

Comment: @RossRidge - I'm working on data flow analysis and I think I spotted the following: I have some value stored in register R; many instructions are executed and then there is an instruction INST that is using R; I was wondering if that is always the case that INST is generated by the compiler because it is known that none of the instructions in the middle modified R, or this can be the case that INST is totally unrelated, but just happens to be using R as part of its semantics; I'm sorry - I know it's not a clear explanation (I'm new to assembly world)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't valid to *assume* anything about registers after intervening operations have occurred. When generating code - especially if you're a compiler - you *know* whether `R1` will have changed value by keeping track of every public state change caused by the instructions you're emitting. If you want `R1` to be preserved, you don't emit instructions that will overwrite it.

To make keeping track of this sort of thing easier, compilers follow [*conventions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions): when calling out to unknown code, they save the values of the registers they want to preserve and restore them after the unknown code has returned. Commonly a convention dictates that some registers ("callee-save") will instead have their values stored temporarily by the unknown code, if it needs to overwrite them; it will be responsible for restoring their values before returning. This promotes efficiency by not redundantly storing absolutely everything. Things like flags are generally assumed to be lost the second the execution path leaves your sight.

When a compiler isn't calling out to unknown code, it doesn't need to follow conventions and can do what it likes. A machine has a long and perfect memory, and it can easily keep a register's value alive across a thousand intermediate instructions by simply not emitting any that will overwrite it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: just one more question: if I understood correctly, in general it is not possible to know whether certain instruction is depending on the current value of a register or is just using the register, regardless of its contents?

Comment: ...wouldn't you find that out by reading the relevant instruction set manual? (not sure I understand that question)

Comment: Your're right - that's probably the way to go here. Thank you very much for help.